# What type of strain relief is this?

Tags: identification

I'm looking to extend the length of a Hubbell GFCI and they have this, what seems to be heat shrink sleeve-type strain reliefs. I am trying to find them to purchase more, but have had no luck.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a molded strain relief to me, not heat shrink.

Comment: The yellow square portion is molded onto the end of the cable and not a separate part. You can see the holes where the internal cable is centered

Comment: "looking to extend the length" - by how much? Have you considered that the GFCI may be configured to work with the length it has, and that changing that length may invalidate the GFCI operation?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have not considered that. I'm adding 18 feet of 14/3 SJTW. This particular GFCI (GFPSTxx15A) is sold in multiple lengths up to 50 feet. However, the 25' option is chronically out of stock.

Comment: @earl Can you get the next size up and store the extra somewhere? As in, wrap the excess in a figure-of-eight. Or, option 2b, contact them directly instead of relying on website availabilty figures, in case the website is stuck.

Comment: I'm assuming the GFCI has a receptacle on it's load side? If so, just extend with an appropriate extension cord on the load side.

Comment: @AndyW No, the GFCI has two of these strain reliefs on each side. The female and male connectors each have 7 inches of 14/3 wire.

Comment: @earl So, plug in an extension cord to the female (load) side. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a moulded strain relief. It's made by squirting molten plastic over the cable inside an injection moulding machine.

It's possible to rip the cable out if you pull hard enough. Then if you drill out the remains,the strain relief can be
slipped onto a new cable and fixed in place using cyanoacrylate glue.

Comment: If the original cable with strain relief was UL rated, the modified one will not be.